# Adding time zone when storing a schedule report with a SOAP call

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am having a problem with setting/storing the time zone for a report job.

I would like to achieve what I can do with the *iReport* designer (*Tools* -> *Options* -> *Compilation & Execution* -> set the report time zone), then all dates and times are presented correctly.

I know that there is a xml timezone property of the job trigger, but this influences only (and of course) the schedule dates.

At present, *JasperReports Server* uses only two cookies: time zone and locale.

Is this something you maybe have to set? But how?